# Must a captured variable type implement Copy trait when closure returned as output parameter?

Tags: rust

Question is general, no particular example.

If we have a function that returns a closure and closure itself returns some captured variable, does that variable type have to implement `Copy`˙trait?

From documentation:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/output_parameters.html

```
fn create_fn() -> impl Fn() {
    let text = "Fn".to_owned();

    move || println!("This is a: {}", text)
}
```

this works, but for some types this solution give error. For example, if a `text` would be of type `Option<T>` it returns error saying something like:

```
`move occurs because `text` has type `std::option::Option<Box<dyn Something>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
 captured by this `Fn` closure`
```

One solution to solve the error is either to change closure trait to `FnOnce` but that introduces restriction that closure can be called only once.
But, if we want to call it multiple times, does that necessarily means that `text` must implement `Copy` trait?

I thought that `move` keyword does exactly that but i'm obviously wrong so if someone could explain details about how this moving captured variables actually works?

Comment: "for some types this solution gives error" - could you share the erroneous code snippet? Simply wrapping `text` value in `Some` produces another error (since `Option` is not `Display`), and changing formatter to `Debug` makes the code compile again. You're probably are using the captured value in some other way, don't you? Also note that `text` is currently `String`, which is already non-`Copy`.

Comment: If the closure moves a captured variable, then yes, it has to be `Copy` or `Clone` or the closure has to be `FnOnce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the type must not necessarily implement `Copy`. The thing is, when you have a `Fn`, it must be callable several times. If you actually *move out* something, then it's not going to work unless you're not actually moving it but just copying it (thus the error). But, the important thing is, you're not necessarily *moving* something out. You could also, for instance, create it on the fly (well, technically speaking, you'd still be moving it out, but maybe the example will help).

```rust
fn create_fn() -> impl Fn() -> String {
    let text = "something";

    move || text.to_string()
}
```

(see the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe518b23d906195916347a0ee4423d72))
Note that, here, `String` does not implement `Copy` (and it could also not implement `Clone`). What makes it work is that this function can be called over and over again, because each time it won't move out something it will need in a future call (here, by creating a brand new `String` to be given out).

---

But, if you're moving out a *captured variable*, you won't be able to do that twice. In that specific case, it would have to implement `Copy` (or just `Clone` and then you'd have to `.clone()` it).